# Apache couchdb system minimum requirements

Tags: couchdb

I checked all the documentation of couch DB. There is no mention of the system requirements.
I want to install CouchDB on AWS nano machine and wondering if it is possible.

***Question***
What are the CoupchDB minimum system requirements? (RAM, CPU, disk)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not seen any official minimum requirements. I have the smallest DigitalOcean droplet running Ubuntu Server with the CouchDB 2.1.1 on it (and it previously ran version 1.6.1). It works well, but is only used as a test machine for a development project. The spec is one CPU, 512mb RAM and 20gb SSD disk.

Answer (score 4):

We run [CouchDB in production on AWS using Docker](https://hackernoon.com/running-a-couchdb-2-0-cluster-in-production-on-aws-with-docker-50f745d4bdbc). In general, we have found that we need at least a t2.medium for each node to keep up with the CPU and memory demands, i.e. each t2.medium instance has 2 CPU cores and 4GB memory.

We are planning on releasing a more in-depth analysis shortly.

Comment: How much scale  couchdb can handle?